# Remove trailing white space from a SQL*PLUS spooled csv file

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have a simple `SQL` script that returns some data from a set of tables and then uses `SQL*PLUS` to spool the data to a csv.

**Script**

```
SET ECHO OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET VERIFY OFF
SET TERMOUT OFF
SET HEADING OFF
SET TAB OFF
SET COLSEP ''
SET PAGESIZE 0 
SET LINESIZE 32767 
SET SQLBLANKLINE ON
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET TRIMS ON

SPOOL "C:\output.csv"

PROMPT "ID","PERSON","STUDY_ID","START_DATE","END_DATE","STATUS","PROGRESS_STATUS","AMOUNT","DATE","WITHDRAWN","SPARE"

SELECT 
       '"' || TRIM(ID)              || '"'
    ||',"' || TRIM(PERSON)          || '"'
    ||',"' || TRIM(STUDY_ID)        || '"'
    ||',"' || TRIM(START_DATE)      || '"'
    ||',"' || TRIM(END_DATE)        || '"'
    ||',"' || TRIM(STATUS)          || '"'
    ||',"' || TRIM(PROGRESS_STATUS) || '"'
    ||',"' || TRIM(AMOUNT)          || '"'
    ||',"' || TRIM("DATE")          || '"'
    ||',"' || TRIM(WITHDRAWN)       || '"'
    ||',"' || TRIM(SPARE)           || '"'
FROM
(   
    SELECT DISTINCT

        A.ID,
        A.PERSON,
        A.STUDY_ID,
        A.START_DATE,
        A.END_DATE,
        A.STATUS,
        A.PROGRESS_STATUS,
        A.AMOUNT,
        "DATE",
        A.WITHDRAWN,
        TO_CHAR(COALESCE(A.ID, A.UI_ID) || '-' || COALESCE(B.PARENTID, B.ID)) AS SPARE

    FROM SOME_TABLE A
    LEFT JOIN SOME_OTHER_TABLE B ON B.ID = A.OTHER_ID

)
;

SPOOL OFF

SET FEEDBACK ON
SET VERIFY ON
SET TERMOUT ON
SET HEADING ON
SET TAB ON
SET SQLBLANKLINE OFF
SET TRIMSPOOL OFF
SET TRIMS OFF
SET ESCAPE OFF
```

The problem I have is the data spools to the csv file as I'd expect, but the last column contains trailing white space. How would I change my setup to remove the trailing white space?

Comment: what does this give: select dump(spare) from SOME_TABLE where rownum=1;

Comment: @sandman so the spare column is calculated (I've updated the question so you can see). Do you still want me to get a dump of the columns that make up the field?

Comment: Hmm no.  These ID fields are all numeric?

Comment: @sandman yep, all numeric - number (10,0)

Comment: might as well do the DUMP then or LENGTH to 'debug' it, since I can't see a reason why it should not trim correctly